# Prediction of group of values

Tags: regression, classification, predictive-models, ordered-logit

I want to predict belonging to the range of values (e.g. age group) based on numerical labels (e.g. exact age). Is, in general, regression or classification more accurate to this problem?

Comment: Age groups are *ordered*. Is this also the case for your actual problem?

Comment: Yup, I have specified ordered and exclusive ranges of values that I want to predict, but my input data is numeric (can be converted to groups in case of using classifiers, but I don't know if it isn't wasting some of the information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard classification models will disregard the ordered nature of your target variable, which loses information.

My first approach would be an ordered logit model, which is an extension of ordinary logistic regression to multiple *ordered* categories, like your age buckets. I didn't find a straight duplicate, but [previous threads with the "ordered-logit" tag](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ordered-logit?tab=Votes) may be helpful, and of course, there is much more material on these models out there.